# Sending error message from Java to Vue.js using axios

Tags: java, spring, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to ask you the proper way to receive/display in the frontend an error message generated in the backend.

In the **Java Spring** backend something like this:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(new Exception("This is what I want to show in the front"), HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
```

In the **Vue.js** frontend something like this:

```
axios.post(registerUrl, formData, backendOptions).then(
    response => {                   
        console.log(response.data); //Irrelevant for this example
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err); 
            //Displays 'Error: Request failed with status code 409'
            //Instead of: 'This is what I want to show in the front'
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try from headers ? .catch((error) => { console.log(error.headers.text); }

Comment: It doesn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
.catch(error => {
  if (error.response) {
    console.log(error.response.data);
  }
})
```